# Background image that repeats to a dynamic length with a fixed footer image

Tags: css, html, background, background-image

How would I go about creating a background which has, effectively a header, body and footer? The header and footer wouldn't need to repeat down the page, only horizontally, but the middle body section would depend on how big the main content div is, so it needs to repeat vertically but I'm unsure of how to get the footer at the end.

Thanks in advance. =)

Comment: you can't do that with just one image. but you can try playing with css-gradient http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Ah, I don't mean do it with a single image. 3 images are fine, I just didn't know how to get the bottom most image to appear after the one that repeats down the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're either going to have to use [multiple background images](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/) (css3, so no pre-IE9 support) or break it up with at least two block level elements that each apply their own background image - a really long image you repeat horizontally (has to be longer than any possible anticipated content could grow the content vertically).

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have misunderstood the question, but have you tried something like this?

With CSS like this:

## header {

```
 height: 100px;
 background: #ffffff url('background1.png') repeat-x;
```

}

## content {

```
 backgroundL #0000ff url('background2.png') repeat-x;
```

}

## footer {

```
 height: 100px;
 background: #ffffff url ('background3.png') repeat-x;
```

}